# Trying to open Python3 from Terminal on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

In terminal on a Mac the textbook says run file by typing  python3.6 .. I have python 3.7.4 so I tried python3 python3.7 and python3.7.4 none of these worked. I have looked all over youtube, google, and stack over flow but can't find it anywhere.

The overall goal is to open a file. For example, python3.6 ex1.py

Comment: have you used [brew](https://brew.sh) to install Python? or how did you install it?

Comment: Straight from the website python.org

Comment: I have been stuck on this all week. I know I can continue to run programs but this seems like it will save me a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: What is the output if you try `which python` in your terminal? What about `which python3`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more detail. "It didn't work" is not helpful - instead tell us what happened. If there was an error message, include it in full. Did your research turn up anything useful? As well, add how you installed Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click ( + holding Option ) the code -> copy ex1.py as pathname

Then open the terminal write

```
cd pathname ( remove the /ex1.py )
```

Then

```
python ex1.py
```

Try python3 if it does not work.

---

Another option is to right click on the ex1.py -> openOpen With -> Python Launcher

It runs directly with terminal

Just rant it here

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. I tried it from inside the directory and I get an error code.

Comment: Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:haha jacobdunning$ python3 ex1.py
  File "ex1.py", line 7
    print("I "said" do not touch this")
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:haha jacobdunning$ cd ~
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacobdunning$ python3 ex1.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacobdunning$